# Get Error Read/Write Excel Sheet

Tags: fileinputstream

Hi In my project I implement Read/Write  excel sheet this code working in my local host but I upload this code on server that time i get error like this below;

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\question(h).xls (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
```

Controller.AdminExelSheetController.read(AdminExelSheetController.jav                                                                                        a:189)

Comment: Make sure that the file `D:\question(h).xls` exists on the server

Comment: In my project code is D:\\ but why take D:\

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\question(h).xls (No such file or directory) says everything.. check file or path

Comment: @ Jayant Varshney I say in my code i write D:\\ but in error show D:\ why ..? and In local this path D:\\ is working but not working on live(Server)

Comment: Hey  guys I want to help